# Laravel 5.4 - User re-enter their password before access sensitive page

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

How to force the user to re-enter their password before access to some page?

Comment: On every request or after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`reauthenticate`](https://github.com/mpociot/reauthenticate) middleware for this.

```php
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    // .....
    // all regular routes
    // .....

    Route::middleware('reauthenticate')->get('extra/sensitive', function () {
        // User will be required to re-enter their password.
    });
});
```